# How to find $\Pr(A)$ if: $\Pr(A|B) = 0.2, \Pr(B) = 0.8$ and $\Pr(A|B^c) = 0.3$?

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

I need help with a simple homework exercise.

How to find $\Pr(A)$ if:
$$\Pr(A|B) = 0.2 $$
$$\Pr(B) = 0.8 $$
$$\Pr(A|B^c) = 0.3$$

I found $\Pr(A\cap B)$ and $\Pr(A\cap B^c)$ but I don't know what to do with. I'm stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have 
$$\Pr(A)=\Pr(A|B)\Pr(B)+\Pr(A|B^c)\Pr(B^c).\tag{$1$}$$

This is because $A=(A\cap B)\cup (A\cap B^c)$ and the union is **disjoint**. So 
$$\Pr(A)=\Pr(A\cap B) +\Pr(A\cap B^c).\tag{$2$}$$
To get from $(2)$ to $(1)$,  use the fact that $\Pr(A\cap B)=\Pr(A|B)\Pr(B)$ and $\Pr(A\cap B^c)=\Pr(A|B^c)\Pr(B^c)$

If you found the two probabilities on the right of $(2)$, then $\Pr(A)$ was one step away.

Comment: Thanks, your answer really helped me!

Comment: You are welcome: it looks as if you were very close already.